# How can I format the formula

Tags: floats, formatting

Hi I need to give the syntax of a formula as a figure. How can I format it

```
\begin{figure}[h]
Formula $\to$ PrimitiveFormula $\vert$ (Formula Connective Formula)
$\vert \neg$ Sentence $\vert$ Quantifier Variable Formula
Primitive Formula $\to$ Predicate(Term,\cdots ,Term)
\end{figure}
```

[image: Syntax as a figure]

Comment: I figured that I could use a table . It seems much simpler than using spaces and indentation for the formula as a figure.

Comment: Did you mean to write `table` or `tabular`? Note that in LaTeX parlance, `table`s and `figure`s are both "floating objects". Either one could be used, in principle, to house the formula.

Comment: I don't think having the alternative `\` directly below the arrows is good formatting; they are "one nesting depth in". I'd indent them a bit more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This typesetting task seems to be handled most easily with a `tabular` environment. In the code below, I load the `array` package to set up separate formatting directives for columns 1 and 3 (automatic italics mode) and for column 2 (automatic math mode). Doing this makes it unnecessary to insert lots of `$` symbols and `\itshape` directives in the body of the `tabular` environment.

The cfollowing example also uses an optional `\fbox` directive to visually offset the contents of the `tabular` environment from its surroundings.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A formula} \label{fig:formula}
\centering
\fbox{%  % framebox is optional
\begin{tabular}{ >{\itshape}r >{$}c<{$} >{\itshape}l }
Formula & \to & PrimitiveFormula\\
 & \vert & $($Formula Connective Formula$)$ \\
 & \vert & $\lnot$ Sentence \\
 & \vert & Quantifier Variable Formula \\[2ex]
PrimitiveFormula & \to & Predicate$($Term,\dots,Term$)$ \\[2ex]
Term & \to & Function$($Term,\dots,Term$)$ \\
 & \vert & Constant \\
 & \vert & Variable \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to figure \ref{fig:formula}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `align*` for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}

\newcommand{\ent}[1]{\mathit{#1}} % `entity'
\newcommand{\alt}[1][\to]{\mathrel{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$#1$}]{\vert}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Recursive definition of a formula} \label{fig:formula}

\begin{align*}
\ent{Formula} &\to \ent{PrimitiveFormula}\\
 & \alt (\ent{Formula} \mathbin{\ent{Connective}} \ent{Formula}) \\
 & \alt \lnot \ent{Sentence} \\
 & \alt \ent{Quantifier} \, \ent{Variable} \, \ent{Formula} \\[2ex]
\ent{PrimitiveFormula} & \to \ent{Predicate}(\ent{Term},\dots,\ent{Term}) \\[2ex]
\ent{Term} & \to \ent{Function}(\ent{Term},\dots,\ent{Term}) \\
 & \alt \ent{Constant} \\
 & \alt \ent{Variable}
\end{align*}
\end{table}

A cross-reference to table \ref{fig:formula}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a different implementation, where alignment is not preserved, which in my opinion is better, because it underlines the independence of the various parts. Also the input syntax is easier.

The default value for the separator is the semicolon, but you can use any character that doesn't appear in the second mandatory argument (I used an instance in the first `\syntax` command just for giving an example, the semicolon would be as good).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath,array}

\newcommand{\ent}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{syntax}{ }
 { \use:c {align*} }
 { \use:c {endalign*} }

\NewDocumentCommand{\syntaxitem}{O{;}mm}
 { % #1 is the separator
   % #2 is the defined term
   % #3 is a #1 separated list of alternatives
  \syntax_format_syntax:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__syntax_item_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \syntax_format_syntax:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  & % for the align*
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__syntax_item_seq { #1 } { #3 }
  \begin{array}{@{} r @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} l @{} }
  #2 & \to & \seq_use:Nn \l__syntax_item_seq { \\ & \vert & }
  \end{array}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Recursive definition of a formula} \label{fig:formula}

\begin{syntax}
\syntaxitem[,]{\ent{Formula}} % use comma just by way of example
 {
  \ent{PrimitiveFormula},
  (\ent{Formula} \mathbin{\ent{Connective}} \ent{Formula}),
  \lnot \ent{Sentence},
  \ent{Quantifier} \, \ent{Variable} \, \ent{Formula}
 }
\\[2ex]
\syntaxitem{PrimitiveFormula}
 {
  \ent{Predicate}(\ent{Term},\dots,\ent{Term})
 }
\\[2ex]
\syntaxitem{\ent{Term}}
 {
  \ent{Function}(\ent{Term},\dots,\ent{Term});
  \ent{Constant};
  \ent{Variable}
 }
\end{syntax}
\end{table}

A cross-reference to table \ref{fig:formula}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How to do this by `\halign` in plain TeX:

```
\input opmac
\def\rmbrackets{\adef({{\rm(}}\adef){{\rm)}}}\rmbrackets

\hfil\vbox{
\halign{\hfil\it#\unskip\ &\hfil$#$\hfil&\ \it#\hfil\cr
  Formula &\to& Primitive Formula\cr
          &|&   (Formula Connective Formula)\cr
          &|&   $\neg$ Sentence\cr
          &|&   Quantifier Variable Formula\cr
                                            \noalign{\medskip}
  Primitive Formula &\to& Predicate(Term,\dots,Term)\cr
                                                    \noalign{\medskip}
  Term    &\to& Function(Term,\dots,Term)\cr
          &|&   Constant\cr
          &|&   Variable\cr
}}

\bye
```